# How do I make a loop in SAP VBA script

Tags: excel, vba, sap-erp

I've got a problem with a VBA SAP script. I have data in excel and I want to execute the transaction code `IW41` by copying and pasting data from Excel. I have all of the data like dates, number of orders, who did it etc in Excel and I want to automate it. I did a loop for variable `i` but I get an error and I cannot fix it.

Error :

> Run-time error '619': Application-defined or object-defined error

Code provided below.

Can you give me some pro tips or help me fix it?

Screen in `IW41` where the error occurs:
[image]

Code :

```
Sub ConfirmPM_Nots()

    SystemName = "CCP"          'change as needed or use a variable
Transaction = "SESSION_MANAGER"      'change as needed or use a variable

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
If Not IsObject(Sap_Applic) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set Sap_Applic = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
On Error GoTo 0
koniec:
qConnections = Sap_Applic.Connections.Count
If qConnections = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No connection to SAP"
    End
End If

bSession = False
For iConnectionCounter = 0 To qConnections - 1
    Set Connection = Sap_Applic.Children(Int(iConnectionCounter))
    If Not Connection.Description = "" Then
    qSessions = Connection.Children.Count
        For iSessionCounter = 0 To qSessions - 1
            Set session = Connection.Children(Int(iSessionCounter))
        If session.info.SystemName <> SystemName Then Exit For
            If session.info.Transaction = Transaction Then
                bSession = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
    If bSession Then Exit For
Next

If Not bSession Then
    MsgBox SystemName & " not available or free session not available"
    End
End If

Do
i = 1
session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 128, 37, False
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "iw41"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

Order = Cells(i, 1)
b = Cells(i, 2)
c = Cells(i, 3)
d = Cells(i, 4)

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtCORUF-AUFNR").Text = Order
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtCORUF-AUFNR").caretPosition = 7
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLCORUTC_3100/txtAFVGD-VORNR[1,0]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLCORUTC_3100/txtAFVGD-VORNR[1,0]").caretPosition = 2
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkAFRUD-AUERU").Selected = True
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkAFRUD-LEKNW").Selected = True
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtAFRUD-ISDD").Text = c
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtAFRUD-IDAUR").Text = b
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtAFRUD-IEDD").Text = c
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtAFRUD-LTXA1").Text = d
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtAFRUD-LTXA1").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtAFRUD-LTXA1").caretPosition = 10

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
   i = i + 1
Loop

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "No connection to SAP"
End

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be difficult to take a worst picture, I think... We cannot see the yellow line which returns the error, which is more important then the error itself. Can you edit your question and copy the line returning the error?

Comment: hello, i made it to make a loop but it crashes at the last one record IN THIS PLACE : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IowTh.png

Plus i've got a question, how to make loop stop when there are no records left?

Comment: How is that loop supposed to terminate? You have no `While` or `Until` condition and have no `Exit Do` or `Exit Sub` in the loop itself. That loop will run until your program crashes.

Comment: It cannot stop on 5 code lines... Try making the next modification in your VBE: Tools -> Options -> General (Tab) and check "Break in class module".

Comment: https://ibb.co/L8vnq14 error occured on the following lane : 
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLCORUTC_3100/txtAFVGD-VORNR[1,0]").SetFocus

Comment: i've been thinking and i know why it crashes on setfocus. Because when you confirm tasks, he clicks the number of the operations (setFocus), then it clicks all the data. But when it is the last operation in the order and u do iw41->order-> it shows confirmation menu without choosing the operation. Do u know how can I fix it?

Comment: After saving (`wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]`) you leave the transaction and you need to re-enter the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

**`"iw41"`** (from `session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "iw41"`) only works if the current screen is the start menu. OK-Code **`"/niw41"`** will always work! So this code might work (untested):

```
Do
i = 1
' session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 128, 37, False
' iw41 only works in the start menu. OK-Code /niw41 will always work!
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/niw41"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

Order = Cells(i, 1)
b = Cells(i, 2).value
c = Cells(i, 3).value
d = Cells(i, 4).value

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtCORUF-AUFNR").Text = Order
' session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtCORUF-AUFNR").caretPosition = 7
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLCORUTC_3100/txtAFVGD-VORNR[1,0]").SetFocus
' session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPLCORUTC_3100/txtAFVGD-VORNR[1,0]").caretPosition = 2
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkAFRUD-AUERU").Selected = True
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkAFRUD-LEKNW").Selected = True
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtAFRUD-ISDD").Text = c
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtAFRUD-IDAUR").Text = b
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtAFRUD-IEDD").Text = c
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtAFRUD-LTXA1").Text = d
' session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtAFRUD-LTXA1").SetFocus
' session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtAFRUD-LTXA1").caretPosition = 10

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
   i = i + 1
Loop
```

I also commented the lines with `resizeWorkingPane`, `caretPosition` and `SetFocus` because this is usually not needed. `resizeWorkingPane` will resize the SAPGUI screen and `caretPosition` is the position of a cursor within a textbox. Sometimes needed if you want to replace text for example. But in this case certainly not.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Your need to exit our Do Loop and place the record pointer i out of the loop. Otherwise i = 1. To exit the loop I often use first blank cell value.
This way you can set the first record to start with, and in most cases i=2 as most sheets have used first row as headers.

```
i = 1
Do Until Cells(i, 1) = ""
' code  
i = i + 1 
Loop
```

When I debugged the code to use it in my own update of Equipment in SAP, I found that our SAP does not have Connection.Description so I just pick up the first session like this.

This worked just fine for me:

```
Sub SetEQLocations()
' Script written by Svein Aren Hylland 02.12.2022
' Use of VBScript recording from SAP to work with SAP transaction IE02 - Change Equipment.
' The sub will transfere new Location data found in sheet on all visible rows with filter and headers in first row.
' Code will show progress in first column while it updates each EQ in SAP.
'

Sv = MsgBox("This routine work towards SAP IE02 from row 2 - and will update all EQ locations as shown in this sheet.", vbOKCancel)
If Sv = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

SystemName = "KO3"          'change as needed or use a variable
Transaction = "SESSION_MANAGER"      'change as needed or use a variable

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
If Not IsObject(Sap_Applic) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set Sap_Applic = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
On Error GoTo 0
koniec:
qConnections = Sap_Applic.Connections.Count
If qConnections = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No connection to SAP"
    End
End If

'MsgBox Sap_Applic.Children(0).info.SystemName

bSession = False
For iConnectionCounter = 0 To qConnections - 1
    Set Connection = Sap_Applic.Children(Int(iConnectionCounter))
    'MsgBox Connection.Description
    'If Not Connection.Description = "" Then
    qSessions = Connection.Children.Count
        For iSessionCounter = 0 To qSessions - 1
            Set Session = Connection.Children(Int(iSessionCounter))
            'MsgBox Session.info.SystemName
        If Session.info.SystemName <> SystemName Then Exit For
            If Session.info.Transaction = Transaction Then
                bSession = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    'End If
    If bSession Then Exit For
Next

If Not bSession Then
    MsgBox SystemName & " not available or free session not available"
    End
End If
'Stop

Session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 154, 24, False
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "ie02"
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

i = 2
Do Until Cells(i, 1) = ""
If Cells(i, 1).Rows.Hidden = False Then

    EQ = Cells(i, 1)
    ' Display progress
    Cells(i, 1).Select
    Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    
    ' Get data from sheet to be poulated in SAP fields
    CostCenter = Cells(i, 14)    ' Organization/Cost Center
    MainWC = Cells(i, 15)        ' Organization/Main Work Center
    LocWorkCenter = Cells(i, 16) ' Location/Work Center
    LocRoom = Cells(i, 17)       ' Location/Room
    
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRM63E-EQUNR").Text = EQ
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP/tabpT\02").Select
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP/tabpT\02/ssubSUB_DATA:SAPLITO0:0102/subSUB_0102A:SAPLITO0:1050/txtITOB-MSGRP").Text = LocRoom
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP/tabpT\02/ssubSUB_DATA:SAPLITO0:0102/subSUB_0102A:SAPLITO0:1050/txtITOB-MSGRP").SetFocus
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP/tabpT\02/ssubSUB_DATA:SAPLITO0:0102/subSUB_0102A:SAPLITO0:1050/txtITOB-MSGRP").caretPosition = 6
    Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP/tabpT\02/ssubSUB_DATA:SAPLITO0:0102/subSUB_0102A:SAPLITO0:1050/ctxtITOBATTR-ARBPL").Text = LocWorkCenter
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP/tabpT\02/ssubSUB_DATA:SAPLITO0:0102/subSUB_0102A:SAPLITO0:1050/ctxtITOBATTR-ARBPL").SetFocus
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP/tabpT\02/ssubSUB_DATA:SAPLITO0:0102/subSUB_0102A:SAPLITO0:1050/ctxtITOBATTR-ARBPL").caretPosition = 6
    Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP/tabpT\03").Select
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP/tabpT\03/ssubSUB_DATA:SAPLITO0:0102/subSUB_0102A:SAPLITO0:1052/ctxtITOB-KOSTL").Text = CostCenter
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP/tabpT\03/ssubSUB_DATA:SAPLITO0:0102/subSUB_0102B:SAPLITO0:1062/ctxtITOBATTR-GEWRK").Text = MainWC
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP/tabpT\03/ssubSUB_DATA:SAPLITO0:0102/subSUB_0102B:SAPLITO0:1062/ctxtITOBATTR-GEWRK").SetFocus
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP/tabpT\03/ssubSUB_DATA:SAPLITO0:0102/subSUB_0102B:SAPLITO0:1062/ctxtITOBATTR-GEWRK").caretPosition = 6
    Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

End If
   i = i + 1
Loop

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "No connection to SAP"
End

End Sub
```